# Simplify vector equation $2\mathbf c - (\mathbf a + \mathbf b)\times(\mathbf a - \mathbf b)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The unit vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ are both perpendicular to a third unit vector $\mathbf c$. Additionally, a is at an angle of $\dfrac{\pi}4$ to b. Simplify the expression:
$$2\mathbf c - (\mathbf a + \mathbf b)\times(\mathbf a - \mathbf b)$$

My working was:

$$\begin{align}&2\mathbf c - (\mathbf a + \mathbf b)\times(\mathbf a - \mathbf b) \\
=\ &2\mathbf c - (\mathbf a \times \mathbf a) + (\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) - (\mathbf b \times \mathbf a) + (\mathbf b \times \mathbf b)\\
=\ &2\mathbf c - 0 + (\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) - (\mathbf b \times \mathbf a) + 0\\
=\ &2\mathbf c + (\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) + (\mathbf a \times \mathbf b)\\
=\ &2\mathbf c + 2(\mathbf a \times \mathbf b)\\
=\ &2\mathbf c + 2\left(|a||b|\sin\theta\right)\\
=\ &2\mathbf c + 2\left(1^2\sin\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)\right)\\
=\ &2\mathbf c + 2\frac1 {\sqrt 2}\\
=\ &2\mathbf c + \sqrt 2\\
\end{align}$$

However, on the mark scheme for the question, the answer is: $(2 \pm\sqrt 2)\mathbf c$

After looking over my textbook and lecture notes, I still don't know where I went wrong, if someone could correct my working I'd be very grateful.

Comment: In the fifth line of your solution, you have replaced the vector $a \times b$ with a scalar. It should be that scalar times a vector (which in your case is $c$) that is perpendicular to the plane of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: in addition, the answer will depend on whether ${\bf c}$ is in the direction of ${\bf a \times b}$ or ${\bf b \times a}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorrect working on line 5.

$$\mathbf a \times \mathbf b \ne |a||b|\sin \theta$$

Because the RHS is a scalar not a vector, and so must instead include $\mathbf c$ as this is the normal to the plain in which vectors $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ lie.

$$2\mathbf c - 2(\mathbf a \times \mathbf b) = 2\mathbf c - 2|\mathbf a||\mathbf b|\sin \theta(\pm \mathbf c)=(2\pm \sqrt 2)\mathbf c$$